# LINQ Query Return unique list of lists

Tags: c#, .net, linq, asp.net-core, nested-lists

I am new to Linq and am struggling with the following problem.

I have some models structure like the following

```
class Order {
    public Guid ID
    public List<OrderItems> OrderItems
}

class OrderItem {
    public Guid ID
    public Guid OrderID
    public List<OrderItemAddOns> OrderItemAddOns
}

class OrderItemAddOn {
    public Guid ID
    public Guid OrderItemID
}
```

How can I query the db to get a list of Orders which contains the related list of OrderItems which contains the related list of OrderItemAddOns?

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! Are you asking about `Linq` and or asking about getting data from a database? Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to improve your question and help us to understand your problem.

Comment: What have you tried? What do you use for data access? Any ORMs?

Comment: What LINQ are you using: LINQ to SQL / EF 6.x / EF Core 2.0 / 2.1 / 3.x / 5.x / 6.x? What database provider?

Comment: NetMage... am using EF 5.x. 

Codexer... I am trying to get the data from the database using Linq.

Guru Stron... I have tried joining the tables and then selecting the data models which returns not what I want. from o in db.orders join oi in db.orderitems on o.Id equals oi.orderID join oia in db.OrderItemAddOns on oi.ID equals oia.OrderItemID select new { o, oi, oia }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Entity Framework, you can retrieve the Orders from your database and their related entities using `Include()` which will fetch any related `OrderItems` and `ThenInclude()` which will fetch any `OrderItemAddOns` an `OrderItem` has:

```
var result = db.Orders
                 .Include(o => o.OrderItems)
                 .ThenInclude(o => o.OrderItemAddOns)
                 .ToList();
```